# error while create Installation setup in vs 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I am using visual studio 2015 community version.
I have create one windows application(desktop) with c#.
While i am trying to publish it, It shows following error

`An error occurred while signing: SignTool.exe was not found at path C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\signtool.exe.`

What does its mean? and where to find this signtool.exe.

Comment: Have you tried searching for `signtool download` or `microsoft sdk signtool`? The links are pretty easy to find... [SignTool Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s9b9yaz(v=vs.110).aspx) / [Microsoft SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where do you download signcode.exe and other tools](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451959/where-do-you-download-signcode-exe-and-other-tools)

Answer (score 0):

i had this problem once. Check if there are updates available for VS and widows 7. I have to had service pack one of windows 7. or visual studio. then the problem was solved.